# How to add CSS translation to existing translation?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I am placing a DIV element on the screen using CSS translate. This works fine, except that when the same element is displaced later, the original displacement is discarded.

**Set the CSS start position with javascript**

```
div.style.transform ="translate(800px, 400px)";
```

After setting the starting position randomly with javascript, the CSS animation just resets it back.

CSS Animation

```
@keyframes testanimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(80px);
  }
}
```

How can I combine CSS translations, to take previous displacements into account? In this case, the goal is to have the animation start at randomised locations. The 20px - 80px should be relative.

Comment: Put your element inside another div! And set the animation on the div!

Comment: That might be the best solution actually? Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: I've posted an example.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this I would guess is to fetch the previous transform, add something to those values and then apply the new transform.

Another suggestion is to set the position of the element using `position`, `left` and `top`. Using the following code for example:

```
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = "800px";
div.style.top = "400px";
```

That way, the transform would then apply to that position instead of relative to your previous transform.

Comment: Thanks, using position left top would solve this specific issue! Even though I'd prefer to somehow have relative css transforms.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about transform, then you need to reset each value in the animation, else it will be overwritten by animation rules.

example:

```css
div {/* translate value reduced to fit in snippet window */
  border:solid;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  transform:translatex(180px) translatey(140px);
  animation:2s testanimation forwards;
}
@keyframes testanimation {
  0% {
    transform:translatex(180px) translatey(150px)
  }

  100% {
    transform:translatex(180px) translatey(180px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Your  style to apply to start width should be :

```
div.style.transform ="translatex(800px) translatey(400px)";
```

and the animation :

```
@keyframes testanimation {
  0% {
    transform:translatex(800px) translatey(420px)
  }

  100% {
    transform:translatex(800px) translatey(480px)
  }
}
```

in order to update only the translatey value

---

translate or position:relative + coordonates have the same effects/results.

You can also combine them

```css
div {/* value reduced to fit window's demo */
  border:solid;
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  position:relative;
  transform:translate(80px,40px);
  animation:2s testanimation forwards;
}
@keyframes testanimation {
  0% {
    top : 20px
  }

  100% {
    top:40px
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

the other way round works too :

```css
div {
  /* value reduced to fit window's demo */
  border: solid;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  position: relative;
  left: 80px;
  top: 40px;
  animation: 2s testanimation forwards;
}

@keyframes testanimation {
  0% {
    transform: translatey(20px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translatey(40px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yeah but the point is that I initialise the starting values dynamically with javascript, and then the CSS stylesheet resets those values again.

Comment: @Kokodoko I understood this , reset coordonates via js and let transform do its thing CSS is not able to catch and add earlier value , js does. Ypur approach has to be rethink . parent and child to dispatch js value and css animation or use together relative and transform to avoid values to be reset

Comment: @Kokodoko position:relative + transform does too . relative + coordonates can be set in animation instead transform if updating your js bothers you :) You can skip that extra wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

An example of my comment above:

```css
#wrapperDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;

  transform: translate(400px, 200px) rotate(50deg);
}

#yourDiv {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  
  animation: testanimation 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes testanimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20px) rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(80px) rotate(40deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapperDiv">
  <div id="yourDiv">
  <div>
<div>
```

The `div#yourDiv` will get a transform relative to its parent `div#wrapperDiv` transform.

Answer (score -1):

I think a more general solution would be to parse the css transform property, as this allows you to keep animating an element without having to worry about its state.

This is the solution I use for this case:

```
parseTransformMatrix = function(str){
  const match_float = "[+\\-]?(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)(?:\\.\\d*)?(?:[eE][+\\-]?\\d+)?"
  const match_sep = "\\s*,?\\s*"
  m = str.match(RegExp(`matrix\\((${match_float}(?:${match_sep}${match_float})*)\\)`))
  if(!m || !m.length || m.length < 2) return null
  return m[1].match(RegExp(match_float, 'g')).map(x => parseFloat(x))
}
// Test parseTransformMatrix method
console.log(parseTransformMatrix("matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 96.2351, 309.123)"));

getElementTranslate = function(e){
  let t = e.css("transform")
  let r = { left: 0, top: 0 }
  if(!t) return r
  mat = parseTransformMatrix(t)
  if(!mat || !mat.length || mat.length != 6) return r
  r.left = mat[4]
  r.top = mat[5]
  return r
}
```

Here, `e` is a jQuery element, but you could easily use `getPropertyValue` instead if you don't want to have this dependency.

Using these functions, you can do something like:

```
let t = getElementTranslate(e)
e.css({transform:`translate(${t.left+20}px,${t.top+80}px)`})
```