# Efficient way to move many elements on the screen based on position

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, position

Say we have a number of divs on a screen:

[image]

...and we want to shift these, in unison, to the left:

[image]

...and to the right:

[image]

A naive approach would be to simply loop through each element, take its current position, and apply the generic shift amount to each div, like this:

```
function set_element_positions(new_top, new_left) {
    var all_elems = document.getElementsByClassName("my_div");
    for(var i=0; i < all_elems.length; i++) {
        var rect = all_elems[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        var current_top = rect.top;
        var current_left = rect.left;
        all_elems[i].style.top = current_top + new_top + "px";
        all_elems[i].style.left = current_left + new_left + "px";
    }
}
```

I can call the above function during an `as_change` mouse event. For example, a slider can call the above function *while* being changed, meaning the function will obviously be called very frequently.

This works well for a smaller number of divs; they move in unison in real time. But once the number of divs becomes large (~30) this start to slow down.

Is there a more *efficient* way to change all the element positions in unison, such that something like a slider can rapidly loop through them all and modify them in real time?

Comment: Why don't you just move the container of all those divs?

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez because if the number of divs is high, their positions extend past the container boundaries. This means that if you adjust the position of the container the far away divs don't come into view. I want to bring those far away divs into view, inside the container.

Comment: Ahh. Ok. ty for the clarification. This question is then, out of my league. Good luck

Comment: Would [object pooling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-pool-design-pattern/) work for your use case? You would only have to update the objects on the screen currently, all the rest wouldn't even be rendered. It's common in games to save on resources. If so, I can write up an answer on it, but I'd rather not if it wouldn't work for your use-case.

Comment: @Tacoタコス That's interesting. But I find that even when they are all in view (inside the container) just those divs move slow when too many. So I don't want you to waste your time on the answer, but it is interesting. thank you.

Comment: I can't quite understand why they can't all be in one container. Could you show an example of the HTML setup (not all the divs obviously, just the basic structure.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, I'll list a few solutions to the problem, depending on different scenarios.

## Scenario 1: Moving all the elements in a single container

If this is your scenario, you're in luck, as this is the easiest to solve. Alvaro was actually on the right track. What you would need in this case is a container within a container. Let me explain with a small example. First, the HTML:

```
<div id="viewPort">
    <div id="innerContainer">
        <div class="my_div"></div>
        <div class="my_div"></div>
        <div class="my_div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, the CSS:

```
#viewPort {
    /* Example width/height. Use whatever you want here. */
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#innerContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
}
```

The idea is to have an inner container that takes more space than the outer container, and have the overflow hidden (unless you want the scrollbars for some reason). Once you are setup, you can either 1) adjust just the inner container's `top` and `left` properties, or 2) adjust the scroll positions of viewPort (`scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`), giving the illusion of movement without actually moving anything.

## Scenario 2: Moving only some of the elements in a single container

This is where things can get a little tricky, since you can no longer use the moving container trick. The scrolling trick above can technically still work if you set the elements you don't want to move to `position: fixed`. However, it would require adjusting their `top` and `left` properties to make sure they stay in the correct spots.

Unfortunately, even though all the elements you want to move have the same class, you can't just update the class on the fly, since CSS styling from stylesheets can't be modified by Javascript. You could try grabbing the existing `transform` property on the elements, adding to it, then reapplying it using `transformX()` and `transformY()`, instead of modifying `left` and `top` ([Previous question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451072/how-to-add-css-translation-to-existing-translation)).

## Scenario 3: You're trying to make a game

Javascript is an interpretive language. Compared to compiled languages, the code won't execute as quickly. In fact, basic HTML with Javascript wasn't really designed to handle scenarios that would handle gameplay, with some exceptions where you could work around the limitations. If you want to make something serious with HTML5, your best bet would be learning about either the `<canvas>` or `<svg>` tags, and work with one of them.